# Spring @Scheduled annotation execute in order for the same time instance

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Configuration
public class Scheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
    public void method1()  {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
    public void method3()  {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
    public void method4()  {
        System.out.println("4");
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
1
3

1
3
2
4

3
1

1
2
3
4

1
3

3
1
2
4
```

The output that I am receiving is completely random on the same instance of time. But I want to order output for the same instance of time in the following way mentioned below:

```
1
3

1
2
3
4

1
3

1
2
3
4
```

Is this possible to achieve the above scenario using the same Cron Expression?

Comment: If the order really matters, schedule one task... and then call the methods in the order that they should execute

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add smaller unit of time:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
public void method1()  {
    System.out.println("1");
}

@Scheduled(cron = "1 */2 * * * ?")
public void method2(){
    System.out.println("2");
}

@Scheduled(cron = "2 */1 * * * ?")
public void method3()  {
    System.out.println("3");
}

@Scheduled(cron = "3 */2 * * * ?")
public void method4()  {
    System.out.println("4");
}
```

Edit: other implementation:

```
public void method1()  {
    System.out.println("1");
}

public void method2(){
    System.out.println("2");
}

public void method3()  {
    System.out.println("3");
}

public void method4()  {
    System.out.println("4");
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * *")
public void even() {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
    method4();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 1/2 * * * *")
public void odd() {
    method1();
    method3();
}
```

Comment: Don't you think, this is hard coding of the cron just to solve the purpose to obtain the order in the code but misleading the accuracy of the time by injecting a delay in seconds? Can't we implement this exactly at an interval of every 1 minute and 2 minutes?

Comment: @tri.akki7 not really, it depends on what you want to acomplish. Other solutions would be to make two methods: one calling `method1` and `method3` and another calling all four in order and make them scheduled. The last solution that comes to my mind is calling `method3` from `method1` etc, but that would require more logic.

Comment: How can I implement this: Other solutions would be to make two methods: one calling method1 and method3 and another calling all four in order and make them scheduled using Cron Expression using if statement for the Cron? Can you quote an example?

Comment: What if, the cron is scheduled in the following manner:
odd method: 0 */15 * * * ?
even method: 0 0 0 * * ?  

And whenever everyday it hits 12:00 AM so only even method should run but not the odd method. The odd method should run for rest of the day apart from 12:00 AM. What would you suggest for this?